# Kernel of a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra

If I'm given a linear map $T:\mathbb{R^2\rightarrow R^2}$ which is represented by the matrix $$\left[\matrix{0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1}\right]$$
How would I go about finding the kernel and image of T?

Also how would I check that $\mathbb{R^2}=$ Ker$T\oplus$Im$T$?

Comment: Write out the definition of the kernel and the image, try to find one or two elements for each and ponder which other elements might lie in there.

Comment: The kernel is just the solution to the equation $Tx=0$.

Comment: So in this case the kernel would just be $x_2(-1,1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel of $\mathbf{T}$ is just the set of vectors $\mathbf{v}$ that maps to the null space, i.e., $$\ker \mathbf{T}=\mathbf{v} \; | \; \mathbf{Tv}=\mathbf{0}$$

So - as your matrix is already on reduced echelon form - you can simple read of the components of $\mathbf{v}$ as

$$v_1+v_2=0 \rightarrow \mathbf{v}=\pmatrix{t \\ -t} | \; t \in \mathbb {R} $$

The image of $\mathbf{T}$, $\text{Im } \mathbf{T}$, is simply the set of vectors that $\mathbf{T}$ can map to. This could be written out as

$$\pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 1 & 1}\pmatrix{s \\ t}=\pmatrix{0 \\ s+t}=\pmatrix{0 \\ t} | \; t \in \mathbb{R} = \text{Im } \mathbf{T}$$

where I just redefined the parameter in the last step.

To check if the combination of the kernel and the image span $\mathbb{R^2}$, simply check if their bases are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your last question in the comments is yes - that's the kernel. And note that the image of a matrix is simply the linear span of its columns.